# Why I can't add system.web.extensions in vs 2012 for windows phone?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I get a message like " A reference to higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to this project". I tried even with lower versions.

Answer (score 1):

There are different versions of the .NET Framework. System.Web.Extensions is part of the ASP.NET runtime and is available only for the desktop versions of the framework. It is not compatible with Windows Phone.

Comment: If i add that extensions only i can perform Java Script Serialization...is there any other way to perform.

Comment: If you mean JSON serialization, you can use the JSON.net library